# Corner Radius Using UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm Trying to round my view's corners using "UIBezierPath". I Only need to round topRight and Top left.

I have used Following code

```
 -(void)setMaskOnView:(UIView *)givenView
  {
UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:givenView.bounds byRoundingCorners: (UIRectCornerTopLeft|UIRectCornerTopRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)];
CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
maskLayer.frame = givenView.bounds;
maskLayer.path  = maskPath.CGPath;
givenView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
}
```

[image]

But my TopRight Corner does not round.

I've used

> UIRectCornerAllCorners

But it does not round my right corners

[image]

Any thing i'm missing??

Comment: Where do you call `setMaskOnView`? Probably before the layout did complete. Therefore the bounds are not correctly set yet and will / do change.

Comment: givenView.bounds changed to  givenView.superview.bounds and check if work

Comment: @luk2302 i call it in viewDidLoad

Comment: There you go - that is the wrong place, you have to set the mask whenever the layout changes.

Comment: But why left one's were rounding??

Comment: and what would be best time to call this if i have to round TableviewCell

Comment: You should write before setMaskOnView method givenView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f and givenView.layer.masksToBounds = YES

Answer (score 1):

I suggest different approach. Load image with rounded top corners and set is as contents of `CALayer`. Set this layer as mask of your view layer. Update size of your mask layer in `layoutSubivews` of a given view or `viewDidLayoutSubviews` of given view controller.

**Loading image as layer contenst**

```
CALayer *maskLayer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
UIImage *maskImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mask_image.png" inBundle:[NSBundle mainBundle] compatibleWithTraitCollection:nil];
maskLayer.contents = (__bridge id _Nullable)(maskImage.CGImage);

mainLayer.mask = maskLayer
```

**[EDIT] Answering your questions in comments**

Either using CAShapeLayer or image as mask you have to resize your mask layer so it will have the same size as masked layer. If we are talking about `UITableViewCell` create your own derived cell and update mask shape in `layoutSubviews` . Below is example code (MyTableCell is loaded from storyboard):

```
@interface MyTableCell ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) CAShapeLayer *maskLayer;

@end

@implementation MyTableCell

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    self.maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    self.layer.mask = self.maskLayer;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.maskLayer.path = [self maskPath].CGPath;
}

- (UIBezierPath *)maskPath
{
    return [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds byRoundingCorners: (UIRectCornerTopLeft|UIRectCornerTopRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)];

}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this subclass

> .h

```
@interface UIView (custom)

- (UIView *)setRoundedCorners:(UIRectCorner)corners withRadius:(CGFloat)radius;

@end
```

> .m

```
@implementation UIView (custom)

    - (UIView *)setRoundedCorners:(UIRectCorner)corners withRadius:(CGFloat)radius
    {
        UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds
                                                       byRoundingCorners:corners
                                                             cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(radius, radius)];

        CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];

        maskLayer.frame = self.bounds;

        maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;

        self.layer.mask = maskLayer;

        return self;
    }
@end
```

Using it like:

```
[YOURVIEW setRoundedCorners:UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight | UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight withRadius:15];
```