# UITextView CornerRadius in cell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uitextview, cornerradius

I have a table, there is a cell which contains `contentView` on which `UIView`, and in it already `UITextView` me is necessary for `cornerRadius` on top at the left, on top on the right, at the left from below (as on the picture)

[image: As shall be]

But in case of an application launch at me shows here so:

[image: as is]

If to make scrolling of the table (scroll that this cell) and back disappeared then, it is displayed as it is necessary. Help to make that in case of start directly it was displayed as it is necessary, here a code which is responsible for it `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
UIRectCorner rectCorner = UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight;

    UIBezierPath *maskPath;
    maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cell.viewMessage.bounds//cell.viewMessage.bounds
                                     byRoundingCorners:rectCorner
                                           cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(20.0, 20.0)];

    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];

    maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;

    cell.viewMessage.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

    cell.viewMessage.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

Comment: if you want it in every cell then put  this code in custom cell class  method 
    -awakeFromNib

Comment: @bhargavbajani I made, didn't help

Comment: please give all cellForRowAtIndexPath code

Comment: did u log the view bounds ? also try to use cell.viewmessage.clipstobounds=yes;

Comment: It could be that your bounds at creation of mask are incorrect. You should resize your mask in cells `layoutSubviews`

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good except don't use content view and add a separate textView instead. Here is my solution for this.

- Create a new UITableViewCell class and create along with .xib file
  (For your convenience. You can create it separately).
- Add a textView into the xib file and create an IBOutlet. (e.g) viewMessage.
- Add thebelow code in the class where you use UITableView,

  ```
  - (void)viewDidLoad {
      [self.tableview registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"UITableviewCellclassname" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
  }
  ```

In the additon to the above, I tried your code and it is working perfect... 
Adjust the corner radius, based on your need.
Hope it helps and let me know, if you have any queries :)[image]

Answer (score 1):

I guess your `viewMessage` class is a custom class.

Add creation of maskLayer to this class in `initWithCoder` and/or  `initWithFrame` remember to update maskLayer path in `layoutSubviews` method of `viewMessage` class.

Check this out: [Corner Radius Using UIBezierPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34897584/corner-radius-using-uibezierpath/34898850#34898850)